# Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb R$. Consider the function $f:A \longrightarrow B$ given by $f(x)=(x-5)^{2}+2$...

Tags: functions, inverse-function

**Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $\mathbb R$. Consider the function $f:A \longrightarrow B$ given by $f(x)=(x-5)^{2}+2$. For which $A$ and $B$ does $f$ have an inverse?**

*My answer*

$f$ has an inverse iff $f$ is bijective.  So I will like to choose a domain which makes $f$ an bijection.
First I find the critical point of the parabola 
$f'(x)=0 \implies x=5$. This means that $A=[5,\infty[$ and $B=[f(5),\infty[=[2,\infty[$. But when I look up the answer $A$ and $B$ are swapped. **Why?**

Comment: There is something really odd about this problem.  There is no unique set $A$ with this property.

Comment: Apart from what has been pointed out (that the pair $(A,B)$ is not unique), your textbook or whatever you use as a resource for this problem may also be wrong.  Textbooks are not flawless.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by unique. I'm doing past exams as training for the upcoming exam.

Comment: There are infinitely many possible pairs $(A,B)$ even if we require that $A$ be maximal (i.e., you cannot add more points into $A$ without destroying the bijectivity of $f$).  There are two possible pairs $(A,B)$ if we require that $A$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  (While there are infinitely many possible pairs $(A,B)$, when $A$ is maximal, $B$ must equal $[2,\infty)$.)

Comment: If $A$ is not required to be maximal, you can just use $A=B=\emptyset$, or $A=\{5\}$ and $B=\{2\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have gotten the answer you seek from the comment section (that is, the answer key is incorrect).  I will show that all possible pairs $(A,B)$ are in a 1-1 correspondence with the set $\mathcal{F}$ of all functions $\phi:[2,\infty)\to \{-1,0,1\}$ with $\phi(2)\geq 0$.  Note that $\mathcal{F}$ has cardinality $2^\mathfrak{c}$ where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the continuum.

For a given pair $(A,B)$, we define for each $t\geq 2$ the following: $$\phi_{A,B}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0&\text{if}\ t\notin B\\
1&\text{if}\ t\in B\wedge \left(f|_{A}\right)^{-1}(t)\geq 5\\
-1&\text{if}\ t\in B\wedge \left(f|_{A}\right)^{-1}(t)<5.\end{array}\right.$$
Then, $\phi_{A,B}\in \mathcal{F}$.

For a given $\phi\in\mathcal{F}$, we define the pair $(A_\phi,B_\phi)$ as follows:
$$A_\phi=\big\{5-\sqrt{t-2}\ :\ \phi(t)=-1\big\}\cup \big\{5+\sqrt{t-2}\ : \phi(t)=1\big\}$$
and $$B_\phi=\phi^{-1}\big(\{-1,1\}\big)=\big\{t\in\mathbb{R}\ :\ \phi(t)=\pm1\big\}.$$
Then we can see that $f_\phi:A_\phi\to B_\phi$ given by the restriction of $f$ onto $A_\phi$ is bijective with inverse
$$f_\phi^{-1}(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
5-\sqrt{y-2}&\text{if}\ \phi(y)=-1\\
5+\sqrt{y-2}&\text{if}\ \phi(y)=1.
\end{array}\right.$$

Now $A$ is maximal if and only if $\phi_{A,B}^{-1}(0)$ is empty, so $B=[2,\infty)$.  If $A$ is a connected subset of $\Bbb{R}$, then $A$ is either a subinterval of $(-\infty,5]$ or a subinterval of $[5,\infty)$.  Particularly, if $A$ is both connected and maximal, then $A=(-\infty,5]$ or $A=[5,\infty)$, with $B=[2,\infty)$.